# how to pass ajax success data to highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

why can't receive `data(str_borrowB)` from `ajax`?
how can I write?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/stat01.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",

        success: function(Jdata) {
            var dataLength = Jdata.length;
            var borrowB = "";
            var back = "";
            for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                week = Jdata[i]["week"];
                flowNum = Jdata[i]["total"];
                borrowB = borrowB + Jdata[i]["borrow"] + ',';
                back = back + Jdata[i]["back"] + ',';
            }
            str_borrowB = borrowB.substr(0, (borrowB.length) - 1);
            str_backbook = back.substr(0, (back.length) - 1);

    //alert(str_borrowB) <--get value OK
        }
    })
```

It can response the `str_borrowB`.
  But I want to pass the `str_borrowB` to jquery function, it can't work.

```
$('#container01').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'picture'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'R', 'F', 'S', 'S']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'number'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + 'number<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal + 'number';
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'borrow',
            //data: [3989, 12452, 13367, 12513, 12335, 9957, 6118],
            data: [str_borrowB],
        }, {
            name: 'back',
            data: [3915, 13188, 11590, 10606, 10318, 9051, 4549],
            //data: [str_backbook],
        }]
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by it can't work? Remember that AJAX is synchronous so you have to call high charts within the success function, or in the resolved promise of the AJAX call. Doing it outside these scopes will cause high charts to fail because str_borrowB and str_backbook are not available at runtime.

Comment: Thank you quickly answer me.Actually, I put the highcharts function in the Ajax success. But it still not work.

Comment: How your response JSON look like ?

Comment: alert(str_borrowB) like this : 3989,12452,13367,12513,12335,9957,6118

Comment: The response picture like this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzyR3QZDnQcvNHNNUUFaMkNKak0
but it have no borrow result.

Comment: Looks like your `Jdata` is coming back as a sensible object, why are you turning it into a comma-delimited string?

Comment: Thank you for your tip.It's work. I read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), especially the section about arrays.
                       `var dataLength = Jdata.length;
                        var arrayA = [];

                        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                            arrayA[i] = parseInt(Jdata[i]["borrow"]);

                        }`